# jQuery Masonry and Plus Slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

Seems jQuery Masonry and Plus Slider don't play together, http://layot.prestatrend.com/?page_id=129 you see, position doesn't right? Any help please? But try to resize the window and enlarge it again after that Masonry works well with this Slider.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){....
```

instead of

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){...
```